# Encoding special characters in url rewriting using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, character-encoding, hebrew

I have a rewrite rule as following,it is working:

```
RewriteRule area/(.*) listing.php?area=$1
```

But when I want to use `%29` in it,but when I rewrite it as following, I get 404 error:

```
RewriteRule area/something%29/(.*)/ listing.php?area=$1
```

Escaping `%29` as `\%29` also not works.

Answer (score 3):

Apache %-decodes the url-path before trying to apply the rewrite rules. So you should not use %-encoding in your RewriteRule. Just use the normal character.

So in your case you should just use the `)`. `)` however is a special character in regular expression, so you should escape those in the RegEx way by adding a slash in front. So it will become `\)`.

Your rule above should become:

```
RewriteRule area/something\)/(.*)/ listing.php?area=$1
```

Comment: Special character can also be written in the notation \x29.

Answer (score 0):

The URL you want to rewrite is invalid as %29 would only be allowed in a Querystring, not a URL. You need to escape the % as %25 (and not with a backslash), so the resulting expression would be ...something%2529 - which should work.

For more in depth information check [RFC2396](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2396.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but problem has not solved.%29 was just for example.I want to encode hebrew characters in this way.Can you tell why how to use %encoded character in .htaccess for url rewriting.

Comment: I don' quite understand what exactly you are attempting to do. However, you can try to escape the backreferences using the [B] flag (provided you use Apache >= 2.2, I believe), or play around with the noescape flag [NE]. More information can be found here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/flags.html.