# Rewrite url with % in it

Tags: .htaccess

I have an URL like this:

```
http://www.domain.com/folder/?p1=%val1%&p2=%val2%&p3=10&p4=0.1
```

When clicked, I would like to go:

```
http://www.domain.com/folder/?p1={val1}&p2={val2}&p3=10&p4=0.1
```

Is it possible to be achieved within the .htaccess file? I want to avoid % sign (can't use %25 in the URL, because of other reasons).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822650/encoding-special-characters-in-url-rewriting-using-htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)%([^%]+)%(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1{%2}%3 [L,R,NE]
```